# Can I make grep treat escaped multiline as a single line?

Tags: text-processing, grep, escape-characters

How can I make tools like `grep` treat multilines escaped with a backslash as a long single line?

Let's say I have some files that looks like this:

```
testvar=test1 \
        test2 \
        test3

othervar=oth1 \
         oth2
```

If I now `grep` for testvar it will return `testvar=test1 \`, 
but is there any way I can have it return `testvar=test1 test2 test3`?

More or less how to treat those multiple escaped lines as a single line?

**Note**: If this can't be done with `grep`, hints about how to do this with other tools like `sed` or `awk` to get the same result are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` setting the field separator and record separators to your use case:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS ="" } /testvar/' yourfile
testvar=test1 \
        test2 \
        test3
```

See the manual entry for [multiple line records](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can preprocess it with something that joins those lines, like:

```
awk 'match($0,/\\+$/) && RLENGTH % 2 {
       sub(/\\$/,""); printf "%s", $0; next
     }
     {print}' | grep ...
```